# How to properly reallocate an array of strings?

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, realloc

This seems like a simple question and probably a simple answer but I am trying to read in words from a text file and allocate each word to a dynamically allocated array of strings:

```
char** words = calloc(8, sizeof(char*));
```

(It must be allocated this way.)

And then I must resize the array as needed. My problem comes when I try to use `realloc()` for my array. I do it like so:

```
if(index == MAX-1){ // reallocate if needed
    words = (char**) realloc(words, sizeof(*words)*2); MAX*=2;
    printf("Re-allocated %lu character pointers.\n", MAX);
}
```

Where MAX is the max number of elements that can be stored in the array.

My array is populated with correct values but when realloc is called some strings appear to be missing! Several indexes are not populated anymore and I get a memory error when trying to print the array out as they are missing somehow.

Here is how I allocate the strings and store them at the index:

```
words[index] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
words[index] = strdup(temp); // copy the word over using strdup
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: What is the initial value of `MAX`? Do you set a null pointer at the end of the array?

Comment: Using all-caps names such as `MAX` for a variable is unusual in C — not formally wrong, but people are used to finding that all-caps are constant macro values (`#define MAX 1000` would be normal).  For a dynamically allocated array, you need three values: the pointer to the start of the data, the number of items allocated, and the number of items using the allocated items.  That's what you're doing.

Comment: Note that the idiom `old_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size);` risks leaking the previous memory if the reallocation fails.  Use `void *new_ptr = realloc(old_ptr, new_size); if (new_ptr == NULL) { …deal with no memory available… } old_ptr = new_ptr; old_size = new_size;` or minor variants on the theme.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your comments, I have updated the variable name in my code to avoid confusion. This possible memory leak is also something I did not foresee, I will attempt to work this in. Thanks again! still very new to C :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this code snippet

```
words[index] = malloc(strlen(temp)+1);
words[index] = strdup(temp); // copy the word over using strdup
```

produces a memory leak. You should write at once

```
words[index] = strdup(temp); // copy the word over using strdup
```

This statement

```
words = (char**) realloc(words, sizeof(*words)*2); MAX*=2;
```

allocates only two pointers of the type `char *`.

You should write at least

```
MAX*=2;
words = (char**) realloc(words, sizeof(*words)*MAX);
```

Also the condition in the if statement should be

```
if(index == MAX){
```

instead of

```
if(index == MAX-1){
```

And if you are using the value of `MAX` then why is there used the magic number `8`?

```
char** words = calloc(8, sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: Ah, that's a pretty silly mistake by me...I have also set it to MAX instead of 8 now. The problem requires an initial size of the magic number 8. Not sure why but that is the initial size of the array.